# Woocommerce add_filter only works when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a filter provided by Woocommerce Composite Products plugin to update quantities of products in a set. When I am logged in this filter works as intended, but when I am not logged in the quantities are not updated.

I use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_composited_product_quantity', 'update_quantity', 10, 6);

function update_quantity($qty_value, $min_quantity, $max_quantity, $product, $component_id, $composite_product)
{

  $category = $_POST['soort'];

  $retrieve_data = WC()->session->get( 'quantities' );

  $postname = $product->post->post_name;

    if($postname == 'product-basis') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strpos($postname, 'product-')) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        $value = is_numeric($retrieve_data[$category][$postname]) && $retrieve_data[$category][$postname] > 0 ? $retrieve_data[$category][$postname] : 1;
        return (int)$value;
    }
}
```

The values of $soort_verwarming and $retrieve_data are available, which led me thinking that the filter is somehow not working when a user is not logged in.

$retrieve_data[$category][$postname] corresponds to a number which should be returned for each product and update its quantity.

Are there reasons why add_filter would not work for not logged in users?

Comment: Are you using any kind of caching on your website?

Comment: I don't have any caching active on the website. When I try it when logged out it does no updating and as soon as I log in and try again it will update the quantities. Clearing browser cache has no effect either.

Comment: Ok. Looking at the `composited-product/quantity.php` template there's nothing that should be effected by a logged-in/logged-out status. This filter only works if there hasn't been a posted quantity. As soon as `$_POST[ 'wccp_component_quantity' ][ $component_id ]` exists then the filter is ignored.

Comment: I've added the answer that worked for me to this post. Thanks for thinking along with me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my header fixed the problem for me:

```
WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
```

I used Wordpress session somewhere else to save some data that I needed to update the quantities with.
My guess is that this session was not being set for customers that are logged out, which explains why it was working when I was logged in.

Any additional info if needed:
https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Session_Handler.html#73-91