# Dynamic discount pricing is not working on non logged in users Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When I'm logged in to my dashboard the promotion and regular price are working but on the non-logged in users its not working. Here's my code below even though I didnt add any roles and restrictions to this function.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'uteplassen_variation_fields', 99, 3);
function uteplassen_variation_fields($args, $product, $variation) {
    if ($variation->is_on_sale()) {
        $save = $args['display_regular_price'] - $args['display_price'];
        $price_html .= sprintf('<div class="you-save save--class"><span class="text">Spar</span> %s</div>', wc_price($save).$product->get_price_suffix());
        $price_html .= sprintf('<div class="sale-price">%s<span class="text">Kampanjepris</span></div>', wc_price($args['display_price']).$product->get_price_suffix());
        $price_html .= sprintf('<div class="regular-price on-sale"><del>%s</del><span class="text if--r_price">Regul&aelig;r pris</span></div>', wc_price($args['display_regular_price']).$product->get_price_suffix());
    }
    else {
        $price_html = sprintf('<div class="regular-price reg--price">%s</div>', wc_price($args['display_price']).$product->get_price_suffix());
    }
    $args['price_html'] = $price_html;
    return $args;

}
```

Comment: I would first try experimenting with `add_filter` priorities. Possibly start with one up from the default: 
`add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'uteplassen_variation_fields', 11, 3);`

[More here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/at-what-priority-does-add-filter-overwrite-core-functions)

Comment: @Jamie_D Try change the number but its not working. It's so weird that the {is_on_sale} is only working to logged in users.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503094/woocommerce-add-filter-only-works-when-logged-in)